# Mostrar cantidad en el stock en la ficha del articulo

Tags: woocommerce

Tengo éste código que conseguí por la web, no tengo ni idea de programación dicho sea de paso.

La función hace que me muestre el número de productos disponibles en mi tienda justo debajo de la ficha del artículo. Cuando el stock es inferior a 4 muestra "Sólo quedan ..."; El caso es que cuando el stock es 0 no me muestra nada y no sé qué puedo añadir para mostrar por ejemplo "Sin stock" cuando la cantidad sea igual a 0.

Gracias de antemano. Un saludo.

---

```
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->stock ) {  // if manage stock is enabled 
    if ( number_format( $product->stock, 0, '', '' ) < 4 ) { // if stock is low
      echo '<div class="remaining">Solo quedan ' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles!</div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles</div>'; 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hola Javi, bienvenido a StackOverflow! Cuál es el problema con este código que estás mostrando?

Answer (score 0):

Una posible solución sería

```
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
global $product;
if ( $product->stock ) { // if manage stock is enabled 
if ( number_format( $product->stock,0,'','' ) < 4 ) { // if stock is low
echo '<div class="remaining">Solo quedan ' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' ud. disponibles!</div>';
} else {
echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->stock,0,'','') . ' ud. disponibles</div>'; 
}
}else {
    echo '<div class="remaining">Sin Stock!</div>';
 }
}
```

Comment: Andres, German, muchismias gracias a los 2. Me habeis ayudado muchisimo y solucionado el problema que tenia.
Muchas gracias de verdad.

Answer (score 0):

Sé que puedes ser un poco nuevo en esto y puede parecer muy confuso, pero trataré de explicarte para que puedas solucionar tu problema.

```
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->stock ) {  // if manage stock is enabled 
    if ( number_format( $product->stock, 0, '', '' ) < 4 ) { // if stock is low
      echo '<div class="remaining">Solo quedan ' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles!</div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles</div>'; 
    }
  }
}
```

Si ves, en tu tercera línea, tienes algo como esto `if ( $product->stock )`, lo que quiere decir es que estás preguntándole al sistema si el producto que estás viendo tiene stock. Para el sistema `$product-stock` es un número, que dice la cantidad de unidades que quedan del producto en el stock, por lo que si tienes 4, entonces `$product-stock` debe ser igual a 4, si tienes 0 debe ser igual a 0. Para muchos programas, cuando tu preguntas (por medio de un `if`) lo que quieres decir es: 'Sistema, ¿En éste producto (`$product-stock`) hay algo?' A lo que el sistema si ve algún número mayor a 1 te dice, **SÍ**, si hay, entonces ejecuta la línea que sigue. O si es igual a 0, te responde **NO**, y no ejecuta el código que está dentro de los `{}`.

Lo que necesitas es decirle que si no hay nada haga algo, y para eso nos ayudamos de una sentencia llamada `else` (Significa 'Si no'). O sea que si no se cumple la condición, entonces has esto, quedando el código así:

```
function bbloomer_show_stock_shop() {
  global $product;
  if ( $product->stock ) {
    if ( number_format( $product->stock, 0, '', '' ) < 4 ) {
      echo '<div class="remaining">Solo quedan ' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles!</div>';
    } else {
      echo '<div class="remaining">' . number_format($product->stock, 0, '', '') . ' ud. disponibles</div>'; 
    }
  } else {  // Esto significa que si no hay nada, vendrá hasta acá
    echo '<div class="remaining">Sin Stock</div>';
  }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado y explicado bien, cualquier cosa que necesites, o duda, no olvides en escribirme y comentar